# Link hover color won't change, but the link visited works?

Tags: css

So my links are the right color, my links turn the right color when visited, but my links aren't changing to the green they're supposed to when I hove over them?

```
.header p a{
color: white !important;
}

.header p a:visited{
color: #FF859C !important;
}

.header p a:hover {
color: #BCD955 !imporant;
}
```

Comment: Try removing "!important" from all 3. This should be used sparingly as a last resort.

Comment: Also, you misspelled important on the last one. That's why this example isn't working like you think it would.

Comment: @LeeWise that's probably why they worked when I retyped them. I've been in such a frustrated state with this project I'm making naive mistakes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a little overzealous with the `!important` modifier, and since `:visited` and `:hover` are equal specificity, `:visited` wins out because it was declared first.

Get rid of all the `!important` modifiers and it'll work as expected.

Comment: Well it didn't work with the Important gone (there's more to this CSS as it's from Foundation and I haven't figured out all of Foundation yet) BUT removing then readding them worked? How odd.

Comment: You should increase the specificity on your CSS selector, then.  Try `html > body .header p a { color: white; }` for instance, or so on.  The problem with Foundation and other kits is often that they are very liberal with the specificity of their selectors, so you need to outgun them when you override styles.